# He cambiado HTTP por HTTPS en al ruta del sitio y 404.Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http, https

Veréis me han encargado un trabajo en wordpress, tengo acceso al sitio.com/wp-admin con el usuario y contraseña. Pensaba que estaba instalado el certificado SSL para poner segura la pagina con HTTPS, así que cambie la URl en los ajustes de http... a https... tras el cambio intento acceder tanto al sitio web como al administración y sale error 404 page not found.
me gustaría revertir los cambios pero no se mucho del tema. estoy aprendiendo.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si solo has hecho el cambio en los ajustes, debes tambien realizar el cambio en tu archivo `.htaccess` agregando lo siguiente:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Ademas, ayuda tambien agregar al principio del archivo `wp-config.php` lo siguiente:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! He accedido a la base de datos del mi proveedor hosting y he cambiado la configuración desde ahí en wp-config.php